# Update dynamic table with JQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic table that looks like the following:
[image]

Each time I click on update, a JQuery dialog box shows up containing a form in order to update  a chosen row. Until this moment, I succeeded at making this update but the problem I'm facing now is that once I make an update, my database get updated but not the table in my web page.
I have two solutions in my mind:

- Reload the whole page after update (I don't prefer this)
- Use Ajax to update the table (this is quite difficult for a beginner
  like me! but I try)

Below is the code to update a row:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../folder/update.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(){
    $('.info').show().html("<img src='../images/success.png' width='30px' height='35' />").delay(2000).fadeOut();
// I guess I should load the table here
}
});
```

What do you think my friends? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just append the entered data onto the table with jQuery? That way it will still show what you inserted without the need for wasting bandwidth?

EDIT -

Oh wait, I forgot you'd probably need the ID's for your update/delete actions. I'd suggest putting the logic of that table in a different PHP script, say `table.php`, and then just refreshing that "container" using an AJAX call to that script?

EDIT #2 -

Sorry, should probably give some example of what I'm talking about.

Say your table is in `<div id="data-table"></div>`, I would suggest having a separate PHP script (call it `table.php`) that actually builds this table for you (I would include this script into the main script for when you load the page initially).

Add the following function to your JS...

```
function getNewTable() {
    $("#data-table").load("table.php");
}
```

After updating your data, call `getNewTable()`, and that's it. Hope it helps!

Comment: is there any example illustrating your suggestion?
EDIT--
That's exactly what I'm thinking about too, it's the 2nd solution I've mentioned

Comment: Just use `$.load()` to get that information. - EDIT check [link](http://api.jquery.com/load/)